# creating a popup in JSF using a custom compoment

Tags: servlets, jsf-2, popup, dhtml

I've got a custom component that I need to use if I create a popup on a JSF page. 
It seems it uses the DHTML technique with CSS hide and show and creates an overlay on the current page, and not a proper window.

In my case, it's to display an image that is served by a servlet.

I have tried several thing and here are the results:
1) if I use `<h:commandButton action="bean.displayImage" onclick="mypopup.show()">` the popup and image are displayed then disappear because the commandButton refreshes the page.

2) if I change the type of the commandButton to "button", then `bean.displayImage`in the action field is never called, neither is the servlet supposed to serve the image

3) I also tried putting the  `bean.displayImage` in the actionListener field and modifying the method by adding ActionEvent e as param to prevent the page from refreshing, but it then has the same behavior as 2)

I'm running out of ideas, can anyone help ?

Thanks in advance,
Michael

Comment: What's the purpose of `#{bean.displayImage}`? What exactly is it doing which cannot be done in the view side?

Comment: its a controller (request scoped), it gets an image in binary64 and puts it in the session map. it is then used by the servlet to render the jpg image.

in the view, I display the servlet

Comment: Well, my answer still applies.

Comment: I'm not sure I can use ajax either, let me check that on monday :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The functional requirement is not entirely clear, but you could use `<f:ajax>` to make it an ajax request instead and render certain parts of the page.

Something like:

```
<h:commandButton value="Show popup" onclick="mypopup.show()">
    <f:ajax listener="#{bean.displayImage}" render="image" />
</h:commandButton>
<h:panelGroup id="image">
    <h:graphicImage value="imageURL" rendered="#{bean.renderImage}" />
</h:panelGroup>
```